# Firewall blocks outgoing email

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

On my Debian server running a Django website, I have an error when I need to send an email.

The error received is

> Exception Type:   gaierror Exception Value:
>
> [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>
> Exception Location:   /usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py in
>   create_connection, line 547

You can see the full error log [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/DSUdItDV3AYP7LgnmZnF/).

After testing, it seems it is my firewall that blocks the request. You can see my [iptable file](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/571018/) (/etc/init.d/firewall). I think the problem comes from the two commented lines that were supposed to accepts all established connections.

When I uncomment them, I have an error `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

Thank you

Comment: And when you specify the table explicitly?

Comment: you mean with `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` ? Same result

Answer (score 1):

Seems like error with DNS on your server or hostname in your Django config.

Check EMAIL_HOST in settings.py. If not explicitly set than it is equal to localhost. If domain seems to be ok (exists or equals to localhost) problem lies in DNS resolution (either DNS server does not work properly or your firewall blocks connects to it).

To ensure problem is within firewall, set default policies of INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT chains to ACCEPT:

```
iptables -t filter -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

and check whether problem still exists.

Comment: When I open the firewall with the rules you give, the email is sent.

Comment: And in the django config, the email_host is set to the smtp server.

Comment: Your iptables config seems to be correct, and yes, without rules allowing established connections it will block. So the task is to now what's wrong with those rules for iptables in your setup. Not very informative message `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.` is known to happen when iptables finds option of not implicitly known module or if particular module does not exist. What is version of debian you're running on? Are there state and conntrack modules in kernel (may by checked with 'ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/netfilter/ | grep "(state|conn)"')? Are they loaded (lsmod)?

Comment: Also, what is output of `sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct`?

Comment: Strangely I don't have modprobe and lsmod. And no folder `/lib/modules`. I have a debian 5 on a OpenVZ server, they maybe use a custom kernel. `uname -r` returns `2.6.32-6-pve`

Comment: Ok so I installed `module-init-tools`. Now I have an empty /lib/modules folder. `sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct` returns `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0`

Comment: I see. Then the issue most probably is that host does not have xt_state module loaded. This can be  fixed by adding `ipt_state` to IPTABLES config var in vz.conf (so it looks like this: `IPTABLES="ipt_REJECT ipt_tos ipt_limit ipt_multiport iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_length ipt_state ipt_iprange"`. I assume that you're hosted somewhere and do not have access to host machine. So, if previous is not the case, as a workaround you can move from stateful packet inspection to stateless (e.g. add explicit rules to allow replies from essential services (DNS, etc))